# How to navigate through disabled QLineEdit widgets?

Tags: qt, navigation

If I have 5 QLineEdit widgets lined up. What's the best way to enable a user to navigate between them (jumping over any which are disabled)?

```
QLineEdit a (enabled) -> QLineEdit b (enabled) -> QLineEdit c (disabled) -> QLineEdit d (disabled) -> QLineEdit e (enabled)
```

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you mean when using tabs to navigate thru the QLineEdits? The tab order should take care of that if it's the case.

Comment: Not by tabs. Navigation by arrow keys.

Comment: I would advise against this. An operating system provides this functionality already with the Tab key in most cases. By adding this you might be adding confusion unnecessarily.

Comment: I can't think of any HIG guidelines where one navigates between lineedits using cursor keys.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [QKeyEvents](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html).

A simplistic implementation would be something like this:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
  //whatever you want
  protected:
  //here, override the virtual function keyPressEvent (from QWidget)
  void QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev)
  {
    //check for the key(s) you care about and handle the event if needed
    //by iterating through lineEditList, asking each QLineEdit* if 
    //the 'enabled' property is true.  When you find the appropriate one,
    //set the cursor to that widget.
  }
  QList<QLineEdit*> lineEditList;
  int currentLineEditIndex;
};
```

The specifics of the implementation would be up to you, of course.

Comment: Thanks dude. Got something going with this kind of implementation.